# Подключение зависимостей

Tags: clojure

```
 (ns csvdb.core
  (:require [clojure-csv.core :as csv]))
```

Есть следующая зависимость в проекте, как добавить теперь нужную библиотеку в проект? Пробовал перейти в папку проекта и выполнить lein deps, вот результат:

> Retrieving org/clojure/clojure/1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.pom from central
>   Retrieving clojure-csv/clojure-csv/2.0.1/clojure-csv-2.0.1.pom from clojars
>   Retrieving org/clojure/clojure/1.5.1/clojure-1.5.1.jar from central
>   Retrieving clojure-csv/clojure-csv/2.0.1/clojure-csv-2.0.1.jar from clojars

В папке ничего не появилось, импорт так и не работает, повторный ввод lein deps не делает ничего

```
(defproject csvdb "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"  
  :description "FIXME: write description"  
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"  
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"  
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}  
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]  
                 [clojure-csv "2.0.1"]])
```

> Could not locate clojure_csv/core__init.class or clojure_csv/core.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.

PS в примере вызова lein deps указал clojure 1.5.1, поменял в project на 1.8.0 (установлена эта версия), ничего не изменилось.

Нашел папку, куда скачался jar-архив этой библиотеки, что с ним делать?

Comment: Покажите ваш project.clj. И объясните подробнее, что значит "не работает". Вы получаете ошибку? Если да, покажите и её.

Comment: Буду дома покажу project, а сообщение ошибки говорит что не может найти clojure-scv

Comment: Меня интересует её точный текст.

Comment: Страааанно, не смог повторить вашу проблему... Версия lein какая?

Comment: Версия 2.7.1
У вас аналогичный код исправно работает? А куда устанавливаются зависимости?

Comment: Да, работает. Leiningen использует локальный репозиторий maven, который располагается в подкаталоге .m2 каталога пользовательского профиля.

Comment: Можете описать порядок действий после lein deps ? У меня там же находится библиотека, может я что то не так делаю при попытке запустить код?

Comment: 1. `lein new csvdb` 2. В project.clj добавляю `[clojure-csv "2.0.1"]` в `dependencies` 3. В src\csvdb\core.clj в `require` добавляю `[clojure-csv.core :as csv]` Всё, после этого можно запускать. Можно даже без выполнения `lein deps`, так как этот шаг автоматически выполнится при выполнении зависимых от него шагов - test, run, jar и т.д. Я для уверенности добавил ещё код, который csv читает и пишет.

Comment: А как можно запустить такой код в repl, а не через lein run ?

Comment: 1. Выполнить `lein repl` в корне проекта 2. Выполнить `(in-ns 'csvdb.core)` 3. Выполнить `(-main)` или любую другую форму.

Comment: Да уж, я запускал repl не из той папки, а для lein run не хватало :main. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, перенеси свои комментарии в ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы использовать какую-либо библиотеку в проекте нужно добавить её в зависимости проекта и импортировать в пространство имён. Для начала создаём сам проект с помощью сборщика [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/)

```
$ lein new csvdb
```

Для добавление библиотеки в зависимости редактируем файл настроек проекта `project.clj`

```
(defproject csvdb "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [clojure-csv "2.0.1"]]) ; <- Необходимая нам зависимость
```

Заменяем шаблонный код в `src\csvdb\core.clj`, созданный сборщиком, на

```
(ns csvdb.core
  (:require [clojure-csv.core :as csv]))

(defn -main [& args]
    (println (csv/write-csv [["one" "two"] ["1", "2"]])))
```

Теперь проект можно запустить с помощью команды

```
$ lein run -m csvdb.core
```

Или в [REPL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL), введя команду `lein repl` **в корне проекта** и следующую последовательность форм в открывшейся сессии:

```
user=> (require '[clojure-csv.core :as csv])
user=> (require '[csvdb.core :as core])
user=> (core/-main)
```

Чтобы не вводить ключ `-m` при запуске или не вбивать в REPL те инструкции, которые уже есть в коде, в настройках проекта можно указать точку входа:

```
(defproject csvdb "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [clojure-csv "2.0.1"]]
  :main csvdb.core) ; <- Пространство имён содержащее статический метод main
```

После этого REPL будет автоматически загружать код проекта и устанавливать его пространство имён:

```
$ lein repl

csvdb.core=> (-main)
```